# ruby capybara code to click a link

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm new to test automation and using Ruby `capybara` with the `selenium` driver.

I want to automate this [page](http://ephox.com/editlive/demo)

Here, I want to click the file menu inside the applet for that I did following but it is not working

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
w=browser.find_element(:id,"editlive").style("width")

h=browser.find_element(:id,"editlive").style("height")
browser.action.move_by(w.to_i,h.to_i).click.perform
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary use case for Capybara is interacting with the HTML dom. Clicking on a link can be as easy as `click_on "text of link"`

But it sounds like you are not clicking on a regulary HTML link - instead you are trying to interact with a Java applet. Capybara + Selenium cannot (seemingly) interact with applets[1].

However the same [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/0tgVaZog4UE) suggests investigating these alternatives which may provide a solution.

- AutoIt + Selenium
- Sikuli + Selenium
- [Fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/)

If you do want to continue with Capybara, what you've alluded to with `move_to` is part of the Capybara Mouse [private API](http://rubydoc.org/github/lanej/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Mouse). They advise against using it - but it might be the only way to interact with a non-dom element.

You might have better luck using "move_to" with an offset
`driver.mouse.move_to(element, H - x, W - y)` where x and y are arbitrary numbers to get your cursor to the appropriate spot on the browser.

Other tools that might help you are: [firebug](http://waltersmith.us/articles/using-firebug-with-capybara) to debug your specs in the browser and `Capybara.execute_script` which will let you execute arbitrary javascript if you need to get really low level.

[1]
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/0tgVaZog4UE